# How to get "program counter" for functions on the stack?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, yield

I was tring to roll up my own version of `yield` for fun. Like this:

```
class YieldJump(BaseException):
    ...
def Yield(returnVal):
    state = getCallerState()
    raise YieldJump(returnVal, state) 
class YieldWrap:
    def __init__(self, func, *vararg, **kwarg):
        # record function and argument
    def __call__(self):
        try: 
            ...
        except YieldJump as e:
            # record state and return value
def totalArbitraryFunction(...):
    ...
    Yield(i)
    ...
    Yield(i)
    ...
    Yield(i)
    ...
for i in YieldWrap(totalArbitraryFunction, arg1, arg2, ...):
    print(i)
```

In order to get/apply caller state, I found I can use `sys` and `inspect` to get `Frame` objects on the running stack (so that I can do something with the caller). From that I can extract all the details including `function` object, stored local variables, and line number that function is running on.

But line number is not detailed enough since there can be nested function calls in one line. **Is there any way to get the return "address" and force python to jump there? Or is there a way to call/continue `Frame`/`FrameInfo` object?**

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: Have a look at `sys.settrace()`. I've done all kinds of wild stuff with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A frame's `f_lasti` is the closest thing to a "program counter" it has, but it's not enough. You can't set `f_lasti` from Python-level code, and even if you could (maybe you're using the "screw the rules" button that is `ctypes`), you still wouldn't be able to suspend and resume frames by messing with `f_lasti`.